# Which version of Subclipse to install

Tags: eclipse, macos, svn

I'm having problems installing the right version of Subclipse to use with Mac OS X 10.9.1 (which comes with subversion 1.7.10) and Eclipse 4.3.1.

http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA says it's necessary to use Subclipse 1.8.x with Subversion 1.7, and to use the Eclipse Market Center to install it. Unfortunately the Market Center only lists Subclipse 1.10.3, not 1.8.x, so I installed the following components directly from the Subclipse 1.8.x Update Site (http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x):

- Subclipse 1.8.22
- Subversion Client Adapter 1.8.6
- Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adapter 1.7.10

Now, when I use any of the Subclipse commands from the Team menu I get an error

> "Incompatible JavaHL library loaded.  1.7.x or later required."

even though Installation Details shows I have 1.7.10 installed. Is anything else required to get the JavaHL adapter to work?

Update: http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL says I need to compile subversion and add a link /Library/Java/Extensions/libsvnjavahl-1.dylib. Now subclipse works but is out of step with the command line tools, so I guess I need to replace all the /usr/bin/svn* commands with the ones I've just compiled. I'm making progress, but it sure would be nice if people didn't hardcode quite so many specific version dependencies.

Comment: What do you mean by "out of step"?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't being clear. To get the JavaHL dylib I compiled subersion using homebrew, so that gave me svn 1.8.5, whereas the Apple-supplied binaries in /usr/bin are 1.7.10. Each new release of the svn client uses its own incompatible working file format so the two clients won't coexist and I had to replace the ones in /usr/bin.It works now, but I'm a bit uneasy about the solution in case a future OS upgrade reverts my patch and breaks my scripts that use the command line svn tools.

Comment: You could install svn at an alternative location (`/opt` ?), and prepend that to your `$PATH`. That way system upgrades won't affect you.